# TypeScript: Map union type to another union type

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Is it possible to map a union type to another union type in TypeScript?

**What I'd Like to be able to do**

e.g. Given a union type A:

```
type A = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';
```

I'd like to be able to map it to union type B:

```
type B = { type: 'one' } | { type: 'two'} | { type: 'three' };
```

**What I have tried**

```
type B = { type: A };
```

But this results in:

```
type B = { type: 'one' | 'two' | 'three' };
```

which is not quite what I want.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use conditional type for [distributing over the members of the union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) (conditional type always takes only one branch and is used only for its distributive property, I 
 learned this method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/43848))

```
type A = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';

type Distribute<U> = U extends any ? {type: U} : never;

type B = Distribute<A>;

/*
type B = {
    type: "one";
} | {
    type: "two";
} | {
    type: "three";
}
*/
```

Comment: This worked. Out of curiosity how does the `U extends {}` resolve as truthy to provide { type: U } ?

Comment: `U extends {}` is true for object types, "value" types like `string`, `number` and `boolean` and literals of those value types. It's false if `U` is `undefined` and `void`, so the statement "always takes only one branch" is not true, `U extends {}`  excludes `void` and `undefined` from the union. I updated the answer to change it to `U extends any` because I don't know if it's actually desirable to exclude types like `void` and `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was suprised that string literals extend {}

Comment: `{}` describes a type with no properties, therefore every value other than `undefined` and `null` match that description (they are a superset of "an object with no properties").

Comment: How do the inverse? From type B `{ type: 'one' } | { type: 'two'} | { type: 'three' }` to type A `'one' | 'two' | 'three'`?

Comment: Ok, this does the job: `type PickFieldTypes<U, K extends keyof U> = U extends any ? U[K] : never;`. Great!!

Comment: Wow this is terrible language design... the lhs and rhs of a type alias should be interchangable!  Meaning `type B = A extends any ? {type: A} : never` should have the same effect...but it doesn't do the same thing as `type B = Distribute<A>`.  Also there ought to be a way to distribute `'one' | 'two' | 'three'` inline without any type aliases at all.

Answer (score 1):

I have found [another solution that uses a utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDkB7AdhJUA%20zgHcUtclgALAJwkwG4AoAegalEigCEEoBvF8CAFzJ0mKAF8cPPpCGlCSCbl6tBeStSxj6dFRy7L%20QgKIAPYBQCGAY2AAeGABooFtCAB84mlCZQIZyzbOADZBUABmFCgAtlAArmgAluiMzFBQAHoA-HRW6ADOwFAiQpyIBjLCGJr0uWgFLIQl%20tKqckSeOfmF5FSqpVIqsj0aHbX1YSixFE1lLbITU9XezBAUkRR5QA), but I'm not necessarily recommending it: I'm still learning typescript:

```
type A = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';
// type B = { type: 'one' } | { type: 'two'} | { type: 'three' };

type B = { type: Extract<A, any> }; // extract all from union
//   ^?
const one: B = { type: 'one' };
const two: B = { type: 'two' };
const three: B = { type: 'three' };
const four: B = { type: 'four' }; // errors
```

FWIW, the definition of `Extract` is `type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;`