# Mapping union tuple types, preserving the distribution

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I am trying to have two distinct overloads for event emission: One that maps to custom events, with well-known listener arguments (And thus dispatch time arguments)

```js
export type EngineEvents
  = ['window-exit', () => void]
  | ['test', (code: number) => void]
  | ['pre-init', () => void]
  | ['post-init', () => void]
  | ['tick-start', () => void]
  | ['draw-start', () => void]
  ;
```

The problem here is to map those types to the dispatch type, without having to repeat all over again, I've tried the following:

```js
export type EventArgs = [EngineEvents[0], ...Parameters<EngineEvents[1]>];
```

But that expands to a tuple that contains a union in each cell, which is not what I want. I would like to have the tupple mapped the other way round, for example:

```js
// Instead of
type A = [ 'a' | 'b', 1 | 2 ];
// Have this:
type B = [ 'a', 1 ] | [ 'b', 2 ];
```

I've tried using the `T extends any? whatever : never` idiom as suggested by this answer: [TypeScript: Map union type to another union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691235/typescript-map-union-type-to-another-union-type)

But it didn't work out.

```js
export type ArgumentExpand<U> = U extends any[]? [U[0], ...U[1]] : never;
```

Is there any way of mapping the union, one-by-one so when accessing the first and second element of the tuple it does not mix them up?

Like a map operation, but for the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) will do the job here:

```
type MapArgs<E> = E extends [string, (...args: any[]) => any]
    ? [E[0], ...Parameters<E[1]>] : never;

type EventArgs = MapArgs<EngineEvents>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdgcwJZwjAbhOwDOAoKQqAXigG0ByAdxQBMB7KgWggA8lgKAaKACgEoSAPijp6SWgF0CRAD7kKwCDk49eAY3q0IALihwArgFsARhABOg4iLETpRKPMphzEJig7c%20Vm%20KkzCJwowehV3OE81H1E-ezkFYCR1AGsmFQBDc1VvYRi7AMcFWnN05gysrwFc238HAG48PFBIKABZdLAAQXMEHAAeGBFSGCg2JThaHHIVcxQENQA6JczevXS4EDJJaPWQOMIAfnIYMgAGSR4lhYAFTPSjCCVzfpOARkkhSSg9VExzBqa4GgGCwwG6vRIbQ64JeiBQaEw2BwQjqUAA9GjyAAiGgTRgsdjALFfJxYpQqLE8QymCwk7EuNweIl0shYkJhJnEwqsxIpNLATLM7lY4qlfmC4lAA)