# How to transform object type to union in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

For example I have a type EventMapping which is a map "eventName -> eventData". I need to store emitted events in a list. Thus I want to transform this map to type Event, so I can't push data of incorrect type into the events list.

```ts
// type which i have
type EventMapping = {
  click: {
    position: Point;
  };
  scroll: {
    top: number;
    bottom: number;
  };
}

// type which i want to get
type Event = {
  type: 'click';
  data: {
    position: Point;
  };
} | {
  type: 'scroll';
  data: {
    top: number;
    bottom: number;
  };
}

// usage example
const events: Event[] = [];

// ok
events.push({
  type: 'scroll',
  data: {
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  }
});

// error
events.push({
  type: 'click',
  data: {
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type ObjectToUnion<T> = {[K in keyof T]: {type: K, data: T[K]}}[keyof T]

type EventUnion = ObjectToUnion<EventMapping>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHtRmQbwB4BcyIArgLYBG0ANMgJ5GmXQC+AUG2HQA4oCiANwjgAsnG7dQAc2QBeXG2TIEAG2AIA1kRyKlybugDOwMMHQgiGLAG5dLW0sMIo6FSu26lYdN0bkqUA56FOhg3mR+zIF2tuycPCgA8hQAVhAIYAAq6ACqIGYgADyZAHxyuADaANLIoMgaEHToMMiZALraXLxEVbQAJnBgcESZ1W0sLBUNTS3tHF38QuB5BeXJaRnZK+aFgsJgYhLSJWxAA)

Answer (score 0):

My strategy is 2 steps:

1. Convert the type EventMapping to an union of keys: so the goal is to get

   "scroll" | "click"

   This can be accomplished with the **keyof** operator
2. From this union I map it your event type. Using the trick mentioned here: [Map union to another union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691235/typescript-map-union-type-to-another-union-type)

The result is:

```
type Distribute<U> = U extends keyof EventMapping? {type: U, data: EventMapping[U]} : never;

type Event = Distribute<keyof EventMapping>
```