# Typescript union types to keys on other union type

Tags: typescript, types, union-types, mapped-types

I've got a union type, say:

```js
type BooleanOperator = "and" | "or";
```

I want to create another union type that is based on it:

```js
type ConditionMap_Good = { and: string[] } | { or: string[] }
```

However, I've only been able to do this manually, written as above, which won't be feasible when the original union has many cases.

I know of mapped types, but what they generate doesn't match what I want:

```
type ConditionMap_Bad = {
    [K in BooleanOperator]: string[]
}

// type ConditionMap_Bad = {
//     and: string[];
//     or: string[];
// }
```

Is there a concept or construct in Typescript to help me define what I want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: Map union type to another union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691235/typescript-map-union-type-to-another-union-type)

Comment: No, it doesn't, because in that question the initial union type is used as a value in the final union, while I want to use it as a key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the linked answer says, you need to use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to "map" over the *union* and you will need to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to get the string to be key of the object type.

```
type ConditionMap = 
  BooleanOperator extends infer U extends string
    ? U extends U 
      ? { [K in U]: string[] }
      : never
    : never
```

Here is also a reusable generic variant.

```
type ToConditionMap<T extends string> = 
  T extends T
    ? { [K in T]: string[] }
    : never
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9nANhAhgOwPKQE4uHbKAXigCJ0ATUqAHzINIG4AoZ0SKAYTjQoEtgfHgFkUYYlGZRYCZOiwRc+QhAAewCLwDOUPmgBmiqAFUoajdqhbg2PQHMp0qAH4TZ9Zoo7Tjpy6gA3lAA2gDSumgmALoAXFY29sFRUAC+vk5xaBAAborpmTl5bODQACpw3LwCQmiiYAA8pe4WXvG2aHYAfBKOTeaeOqXprkFhEVClsW2JyWl+BbnYrMUcpQAMEuWV-IIiYvXwSKiYOHgEnUA)