# How to define the second property using the value of the first property in TypeScript interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, zod

Here is an example.

```
const a = {
  type: 'file',
  file: 'foo',
}
const b = {
  type: 'emoji',
  emoji: 'bar',
}
const c = {
  type: 'external',
  external: 'baz',
}
```

The second property is always `string`. The main problem is using the value of `type` as a key, using generic.

Would be better if using `zod` and `TypeScript` both!

I have tried

```
type IconType = 'file' | 'emoji' | 'external'

type IconFile<T extends IconType = IconType> = {
  type: T
  [key in T]: string
}
```

But there is an error: `A mapped type may not declare properties or methods`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems to solve:

**Problem 1: Mapped type with extra properties**

You need to use [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types):

```ts
type IconType = 'file' | 'emoji' | 'external'

type IconFile<U extends IconType & string> = { type: U } & { [P in U]: string }

const x: IconFile<'file'> = {
  type: 'file',
  file: 'string'
}
```

Note the extra generic argument on IconFile of type string.

**Problem 2: Map union type to another union type**

We'd like to get a type equal to `IconFile<'file'> | IconFile<'emoji'> | IconFile<'external'>`

You can use conditional type for [distributing over the members of the union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types)

```ts
type DistributeToIconFile<U extends IconType & string> = U extends string 
  ? IconFile<U> 
  : never;
  
type IconFileAsUnion = DistributeToIconFile<IconType>
    // ^? 
    // type IconFileAsUnion = IconFile<'file'> | IconFile<'emoji'> | IconFile<'external'>

const a: IconFileAsUnion = {
  type: 'file',
  file: 'myfile'
};
```

See [TypeScript: Map union type to another union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691235/typescript-map-union-type-to-another-union-type)

Note that simple `IconFile<IconType>` does not distribute the union members

```ts
const nodDistributedBadApproach: IconFile<IconType> = {
  type: 'file',
  file: 'string1',
  emoji: 'string2',
  external: 'string3'
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6&ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgxgewHYBVzQLxQOQDMCWANhNlAD44QC2CAVvqRdhAB7AQBOSAhodgFD9QkWIiQAxIhAA8AVSit2SACYBnUcjQiAZFFXAO+JAHMAfFCwBvKMIgAuKPIC+UXdYDaABShHHAXQd9QxMoJ0ExfSgWB3hkSWJpPClscyt+KBt0ByTibAAadKgCYmygo2MBMKF0KAARfDKAIwBXdhQEWIkpOQU2CBV1Tq1oXTKTVMdepTU9A3KoQoB+DS6E2XNChyQIADdOAG5C6pFO+IgAQVVZJHxkCzqGuZa2jrEz6SH0U0KMgHpfqAAPUW4WQkW4MTeUku11uSHulkKtmyxRIBQyqOyVBAqMqhyAA)

Comment: So nice of you! That's exactly what I want!
btw, do you know how to complete it using `zod`?

Comment: `z.switch` seems like a correct api to use, given that zod is considering deprecation of `z.discriminatedUnion`. See: https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/2106

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) are used to transform the properties of an existing type, not to introduce new properties.
You could use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgxgewHYBVzQLxQEQDMCWANhNlAD44QC2CAVvqRdhAB7AQBOSAhodgNwAoQaEixESAGJEIAHhRRW7JABMAzuORpIAPihYA3oKhQA2gGko%20JFBQBdAFxQ1wDtYDmQgL5QAZFCMTUQgnFG8hQQkXKG4neGRpYlk8GWw9Q2MoYKcU4mwAGkyCYhzcBARsQS8hKOAoACM4iUS5Zhp6NP0AzOzKdoZCk2o6fBz67g5K6sjkaLgmhJlkpU4ePnTuoPQcla5eAszdtbHuAC8poSA) without default generic parameter for `IconFile<T extends IconType>` like so:

```
type IconType = "file" | "emoji" | "external";

type IconFile<T extends IconType> = {
  [K in T]: string;
} & {
  type: T;
};

const a: IconFile<"file"> = {
  type: "file",
  file: "foo"
};
const b: IconFile<"emoji"> = {
  type: "emoji",
  emoji: "bar"
};
const c: IconFile<"external"> = {
  type: "external",
  external: "baz"
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgxgewHYBVzQLxQEQDMCWANhNlAD44QC2CAVvqRdhAB7AQBOSAhodgNwAoQaEixESAGJEIAHhRRW7JABMAzuORpIAPihYA3oKhQA2gGko%20JFBQBdAFxQ1wDtYDmQgL5QAZFCMTUQgnFG8hQQkXKG4neGRpYlk8GWw9Q2MoYKcU4mwAGkyCYhzcBARsQS8hKOAoACM4iUS5Zhp6NP0AzOzKdoZCk2o6fBz67g5K6sjkaLgmhJlkpU4ePnTuoPQcla5eAszdtbHuAC8poSA)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
type Filter<U, T extends Partial<U>> = Extract<U, T>;
type IconType = "file" | "emoji" | "external";

interface FileFile {
  type: Filter<IconType, 'file'>;
  file: 'foo';
}

interface EmojiFile {
  type: Filter<IconType, 'emoji'>;
  emoji: 'bar';
}

interface ExternalFile {
  type: Filter<IconFile, 'external'>;
  external: 'baz';
}

type IconFile = FileFile | EmojiFile | ExternalFile;
```